# NameError: name 'download_image' is not defined

Tags: python, django, nameerror

this is my models.py file

```
class Post(models.Model):
    """docstring for Post"""
    poster = models.ForeignKey(User, null= False,blank=True, default=User.objects.get(username="admin"))
    post_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts', null=True, blank=True)



    def save(self, url='', *args, **kwargs):
        if self.post_image != '' and url != '': # Don't do anything if we don't get passed anything!
            image = download_image(url) # See function definition below
            try:
                filename = urlparse.urlparse(url).path.split('/')[-1]
                self.post_image = filename
                tempfile = image
                tempfile_io = io.StringIO() # Will make a file-like object in memory that you can then save
                tempfile.save(tempfile_io, format=image.format)
                self.post_image.save(filename, ContentFile(tempfile_io.getvalue()), save=False) # Set save=False otherwise you will have a looping save method
            except Exception as e:
                print ("Error trying to save model: saving image failed: " + str(e))
                pass
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def download_image(url):
        """Downloads an image and makes sure it's verified.

        Returns a PIL Image if the image is valid, otherwise raises an exception.
        """
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'} # More likely to get a response if server thinks you're a browser
        r = urllib.Request(url, headers=headers)
        request = urllib.urlopen(r, timeout=10)
        image_data = io.StringIO(request.read()) # StringIO imitates a file, needed for verification step
        img = Image.open(image_data) # Creates an instance of PIL Image class - PIL does the verification of file
        img_copy = copy.copy(img) # Verify the copied image, not original - verification requires you to open the image again after verification, but since we don't have the file saved yet we won't be able to. This is because once we read() urllib2.urlopen we can't access the response again without remaking the request (i.e. downloading the image again). Rather than do that, we duplicate the PIL Image in memory.
        if valid_img(img_copy):
            return img
        else:
            # Maybe this is not the best error handling...you might want to just provide a path to a generic image instead
            raise Exception('An invalid image was detected when attempting to save a Product!')

    def valid_img(img):
        """Verifies that an instance of a PIL Image Class is actually an image and returns either True or False."""
        type = img.format
        if type in ('GIF', 'JPEG', 'JPG', 'PNG'):
            try:
                img.verify()
                return True
            except:
                return False
        else: return False  

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post_image.url
```

and my view.py is

```
def createpost(request):
    # Handle file upload
    new_img_id = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        external_url = request.POST['url']

        p = Post(poster=request.user)
        p.save(external_url)
        new_img_id=p.id

    post = Post.objects.filter(id=new_img_id)
    return render_to_response('create.html',{'post': post},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and this is where the url gets called

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/create/",
      data: {'url': newURL, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken},
      success: function(){}
      });
```

in the console I am getting this

```
in save
NameError: name 'download_image' is not defined
```

and in the browser console I'm getting this

```
POST http://localhost:8000/create/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

If anyone can understand where the origin or this problem may be please help :D
I did try changing the order of the defs but there was not difference

Comment: Your `download_image` should be before the function that calls it. The order of the def should be: 1st valid_img, 2nd download_image, 3rd the rest... and: Who is the owner of the images ? Have Apache/Nginx/Django permissions on the folder/files ?

Comment: Please can you fix your indentation in the models? I can't tell if `download_image` is inside the class or not.

Comment: And @Liarez : no, order of functions is unimportant.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I believe you because you have more experience, but I think I remember having some troubles in some projects because of this, using functions if they weren't defined before of the function that calls it

Comment: @DanielRoseman in my file it is indented well but here it removed the indentation. yes it belongs to the model Post

Comment: 1) You need +4space in front of every row to display it correctly. 2) It seems save to assume that `download_image` is a method of the `Post` model, because there is a `__unicode__` special method at the bottom of the file. 3) In that case you have to call `self.download_image` (it is a instance method) and that problem should resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you functions are methods of Post, you need to call them as such. Methods are always referred to via the instance, so in this case `self.download_image(url)`, and always need to take `self` as the first parameter, so `def download_image(self, url)`. Both of these also apply to `valid_img`.

Note also that it is a very bad idea to override the signature of the save method. Lots of code both in Django and in third-party applications will not be expecting that parameter. Instead, get it from kwargs:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    url = kwargs.pop('url', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make an object method, first parameter should be self and you can call method via self.download_image(...)

Also you should write download_image method inside save method, if you want to use like this.

```
def save(self, ...):
    def download_image():
        ...
    download_image()
```